# Selection of spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have two spinners on the page i am putting the data in that from same array.Both are showing data in same order.I want to show the data in the second spinner that is not selected in the first spinner .Means both have different selected data at on create.How could i do this please help me .

**Spinner Code**

```
private void loadDepartureSpinnerData() {
        Spinner departSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.departLocationId);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.city_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       departSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


private void loadArrivalSpinnerData() {
        Spinner arrivalSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.arrivalLocationId);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrivaladapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.city_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        arrivaladapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        arrivalSpinner.setAdapter(arrivaladapter);
    }
```

Comment: Both have a different arrays??

Comment: basically do you want to select different values on load??

Comment: same array they have i want to show diffrent selected values from the same array

Comment: @ArmaanStranger yup oncreate from the same array diffrent values to be show selected

Comment: you can try sp.setSelection(0) and sp2.setSelection(1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simple you can do this like for depart

```
departSpinner.setSelection(0);
```

For arrival

```
arrivalSpinner.setSelection(1);
```